# How to cast IDispatch in C#

Tags: c#, com, msxml

I've been developing a web-service in c# to link web-site with local db. SDK for local application is a COM object. The second day I am breaking my mind on how to convert the below VB code(given in SDK protocol) to C# equivalent:

```
XML_DOM := CreateOleObject('MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0') as IXMLDOMDocumen
GetData(XML_DOM as Idispatch)
```

I've tried this:

```
System.Type objType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PERCo_S20_SDK.ExchangeMain");
            dynamic comObject = System.Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
            if (comObject.SetConnect("192.168.1.14", "211", "ADMIN", "") != 0)
            {
                    //Could not connect to server!
            }
            XmlDocument dep_xml = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDeclaration dep_xml_decl = dep_xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
            XmlElement root = dep_xml.DocumentElement;
            dep_xml.InsertBefore(dep_xml_decl, root);
            XmlElement element = dep_xml.CreateElement(string.Empty, "documentrequest", string.Empty);
            element.SetAttribute("type", "subdiv");
            dep_xml.AppendChild(element);
            comObject.GetData(dep_xml as IDispatch);
            comObject.Disconnect();
```

with

```
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        private interface IDispatch
        {
            [PreserveSig]
            int GetTypeInfoCount(out int Count);

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetTypeInfo
            (
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int iTInfo,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int lcid,
              out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeInfo typeInfo
            );

            [PreserveSig]
            int GetIDsOfNames
            (
              ref Guid riid,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                string[] rgsNames,
              int cNames,
              int lcid,
              [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] rgDispId
            );

            [PreserveSig]
            int Invoke
            (
              int dispIdMember,
              ref Guid riid,
              uint lcid,
              ushort wFlags,
              ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DISPPARAMS pDispParams,
              out object pVarResult,
              ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.EXCEPINFO pExcepInfo,
              out UInt32 pArgErr
            );
        }
```

but I get error

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not convert argument 0 for call to GetData.
```

Please help me out how should I cast IDispatch in C#.

Comment: Clearly you are using the .NET XmlDocument class, not the unmanaged flavor of it (MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0).  It cannot be converted to IDispatch.  Project > Add Reference > COM tab, select "Microsoft XML, v3.0"

Comment: @HansPassant Added reference to"Microsoft XML, v3.0" . What should be the passing parameter part:  GetData(XML_DOM as Idispatch) ?

Comment: Use `new MSXML2.DOMDocument30()` to create the object, no cast necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant tried out this: var xml_dom = new MSXML2.DOMDocument30();
            comObject.GetData(xml_dom);   but receiving this error:  An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Comment: @HansPassant  Sorry, the last error was occuring because of connection failure to server DB. Thank you for your help as it is exactly what I want. Please create an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not convert argument 0 for call to **GetData**.

Your problem is here:

```
 XmlDocument dep_xml = ...
 comObject.GetData(dep_xml as IDispatch);  // <------ BANG!!
```

`XmlDocument` is not a standard *OLE automation/dispatch type*.  It is not a:

- `int`
- `float`
- `char`
- `BSTR`
- `SAFEARRAY`
- [etc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc237562.aspx)

...or an object exposing `IDispatch`, a COM interface that `XmlDocument` does not implement.  `XmlDocument` would require `[ComVisible]` to be present.

If the object were COM-compliant, then you could just:

```
 comObject.SomethingOrOther(myComCompliantObject);
```

...without the unnecessary cast.

Comment: What is the workaround? Which object should I use in order to implement IDispatch?

Comment: The only work-around I can think of is if you have access to the source of the COM library and are able to make it c++/CLI, then you can pass in any old `object` to the COM method, then once inside you can cast (well it's not actually casting) the `IUnknown` to a managed object of a known type.  I had to do this once with legacy code. I'll post a code fragment tomorrow

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to source of the COM. Can the required COM method be called with: comObject.GetType().InvokeMember("GetData" .....  If yes, then how?